# Vue component with height of 100% changes height on v-if re-render

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue component, which has the class "tab-body-wrapper" whose purpose is to display the "slot" for whichever tab is currently active.

***After troubleshooting, it appears that this ".tab-body-wrapper" component, which I have set a height of 100% in my CSS, reduces in height during the v-if re-render even though the height of the element that contains it (".sub-menu-tabs-body") remains exactly the same at the same point in time.***

**My Vue component (with class of "tab-body-wrapper")**

```
Vue.component("tab", {
    template: `
        <div v-if="isActive"
            class="tab-body-wrapper">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    `,
    props: {
        name: { required: true },
        icon: { required: true },
        selected: { default: false }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            isActive: false
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.isActive = this.selected;
    }
});
```

**The red arrow below shows where this Vue component resides within the DOM**

[image]

**The relevant CSS**

```
.sub-menu-tabs-wrapper,
.sub-menu-tabs-body,
.tab-body-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
```

The way I troubleshot my problem was by placing the following code in the mounted() hook of my other Vue component, which is contained in the **slot of the above Vue component**.

**Below is the troubleshooting code in the mounted hook of my other Vue component, which resides in the slot.** Note that I also used getBoundingClientRect and the results were the same so the issue is not with d3.

```
console.log(d3.select(".sub-menu-tabs-wrapper").style("height"));
console.log(d3.select(".sub-menu-tabs-body").style("height"));
console.log(d3.select(".tab-body-wrapper").style("height"));
```

**On initial render, the heights were as expected:**

```
scripts.js:791 1207px // .sub-menu-tabs-wrapper
scripts.js:792 1153px // .sub-menu-tabs-body
scripts.js:793 1151px // .tab-body-wrapper
```

**However, upon clicking away and then clicking back onto the tab, you can see that the containing element (".sub-menu-tabs-body") retains its height of 1153px but ".tab-body-wrapper" has shrunk to 574.5px.**

```
scripts.js:791 1207px // .sub-menu-tabs-wrapper
scripts.js:792 1153px // .sub-menu-tabs-body
scripts.js:793 574.5px // .tab-body-wrapper
```

**What's stranger is that when I console.log the height of ".tab-body-wrapper" afterwards, I get 1151px.**

[image]

For some context, the reason why I need the height of ".tab-body-wrapper" to be correct during the render is because I have a bunch of d3 charts that use the height and width of elements within ".tab-body-wrapper" during the render to determine their respective height and width. As such, the issue I am having is causing these charts to render with the incorrect height and width.

Note that using v-show for my tab component is not an option for reasons I will not go into here.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the calculation in [`this.$nextTick()`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) as described here: https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/394 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the calculation in a [`this.$nextTick()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) callback. As stated by the docs it will:

> Defer the callback to be executed after the next DOM update cycle

so the element is correctly rendered when executing it.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    pRect: 0
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.pRect = document.querySelector('p').getBoundingClientRect();
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <p>My BoundingClientRect is: {{ pRect }}<p>
  </div>
</body>
```